# How to increase font size in Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, font

How do you increase the font size in the Mac App Store? I have just gotten a new Apple Cinema Display and I'm getting used to the higher resolution. I like it and don't wish to lower it. I have just been increasing the font size etc. wherever I can. The only place where I've found it to be a real issue is in the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Having just checked all prefs that I thought might have an effect on this, the only option I found was in the "Seeing" tab in Universal in System Preferences.  There, you have a Keyboard shortcut available to turn on/off Zoom.

Sorry, but that is the best answer I can give you.  Perhaps others will chime in with something better.

Comment: Right, I have actually been using zoom quite a bit for Mac App Store. The obvious drawbacks to that is the pixelation and the need to zoom out after finishing; plus it's a little disorientating.